# Linkedin API - OAuth.io

Tags: json, api, share, linkedin-api, oauth.io

I'm developing an application that uses the Linkedin API.
Php for the back-end. I used the library OAuth.io ([SDK](https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-php)) and their service but I have a problem: I can't publish an update on linkedin.
I used the syntax provided by SDK with the correct endpoint:

```
$request_object_li->post('/v1/people/~/shares?format=json', array('commment'=> 'Hello world!'));
```

I get this response:

```
Couldn't parse share document.
Unexpected element: CDATA.
```

According to the Linkedin's documentation I should include into the header these two lines:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-li-format: json
```

How do I put them? The documentation of OAuth.io says nothing about. Someone has already worked with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-php/blob/master/src/OAuth_io/RequestObject.php#L112, `post` takes a third parameter `headers` that can be leveraged as follows:

```
$request_object_li->post('/v1/people/~/shares?format=json', array('commment'=> 'Hello world!'), array('Content-Type'=>'application/json','x-li-format'=>'json');
```

Comment: The ?format=json URL argument instructs LinkedIn's API to return the results of a particular call in JSON format.  Both header values are required when sending data in to LinkedIn.

Comment: no, see: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api which says: `If it is more convienent for your application to work with data in JSON format, you can request that APIs return you JSON data using one of the following methods: 1. Add a format=json URL argument to the end of your API call.
2. Add this HTTP header to your API call: x-li-format: json`

Comment: I wrote those docs :)  Apologies if it's unclear, however the intent was that if you are requesting data from the API, you/docs are correct ... either will do.  If you are *sending* data to LinkedIn in JSON format, both header values are required.

Comment: ok, I don't follow the logic, nor do I think the docs reflect it, but I've modified the answer..